# Can we hope to solve all Diophantine equations?

Tags: lo.logic

According to Godel result, neither ZFC nor other particular theory is strong enough to resolve all questions about, say, Diophantine equations. But maybe we can hope that a sequence of theories will help? It is known that ZFC-1 theory (ZFC + Cons(ZFC) ) is much stronger than ZFC, in sense that now there are theorems with extremely shorter proofs, and many new theorem are now decidable. If we continue this to ZFC-2, .., ZFC-n, ... then ZFC-w which is union of all, ZFC-(w+1) and so on, we can continue to extremely large sets of theories, about all of them we have no doubts, and maybe now for every natural Diophantine equation we can choose a theory witch resolve it? Moreover, if we would be able to imagine non-enumerable set of such theories, may be we could hope that for EVERY Diophantine equation has a corresponding theory from this set in which it can be resolved? Or this is trivially incorrect “conjecture”? It seems that this does not contradict to Godel Theorem, which consider one theory, not a sequence of theories.

Another way of thinking about the same idea is to take only axioms from ZFC but add a new derivation rule, which would say that "from any set of axioms A it follows that A is consistent". With this derivation rule we would derive Cons(ZFC) in one step! So, for some reasons (by the way, I do not understand why) Godel theorem is not applicable here. May we hope that with ZFC extended with such a new derivation rule we can, say, solve all Diophantine equations?

Comment: Am I missing something here?  I'd have said it was Matijasevich's theorem, proved in 1970 relying on earlier work of Putnam, Davis, and Robinson, that says you can't "resolve all questions about Diophantine equations".

Comment: See also this related question and my answer there - http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12865/using-consistency-to-create-new-axioms-in-set-theory

Comment: 2 Michael Herdy
Matijasevich's theorem states that there is no single algorithm for all equations, or, equivalently, no single theory can resolve all of them. My question is that may be the sequence of theories can help. But, as noted by Prof. Joel David Hamkins, this particular sequence is inside a single theory ZFC+Inaccessible, so it will no work. But may be other sequences may help?   

Answer (score 23):

On the one hand, no consistent theory $T$ that we can
describe by giving a computable enumeration of its axioms
can settle all Diophantine equations. The reason is that
for any such theory $T$, we can construct an integer
polynomial $p_T(\vec x)$ that has a solution in the
integers if and only if $T$ is inconsistent. Thus, since
$T$ is consistent, $p_T$ will have no solutions, but $T$
will not prove this.

One may construct $p_T$ by understanding the MRDP solution
to Hilbert's 10th problem. In that argument, for any Turing
machine program, one may construct a polynomial whose
solutions correspond to halting instances of the program.
But consider the program that searches for a proof of a
contradiction in $T$, halting only when one is found. The
corresponding polynomial $p_T$ for this program will have a
solution if and only if the program halts, which is if and
only if $T$ is inconsistent, as desired.

So we cannot hope to settle all Diophantine equations with
respect to one computably enumerable theory.

Nevertheless, we can describe theories that solve all
Diophantine equations in other ways. For example, the
theory TA known as *True Arithmetic*, extends PA and consists precisely of
the first order assertions that are true in the standard
model $\langle \mathbb{N},+,\cdot,0,1,\lt\rangle$. (One could use $\mathbb{Z}$ in place of $\mathbb{N}$ here, or just realize that $\mathbb{Z}$ is interpretable in $\mathbb{N}$.) Our
background theory ZFC proves that TA is consistent and
complete, and it certainly correctly settles all the
Diophantine equations, proving of exactly those polynomials
that have solutions that they do have solutions and of the others that they do not. So this
theory is the kind of limit theory you requested. But the
difficulty with TA and with any of the non-enumerable limit
theories that you seek, is that it is too difficult to
recognize the axioms. We cannot tell if a proof from TA
is legitimate, because we cannot even recognize the axioms.

For the purpose of settling Diophantine equations, it would
suffice to use $TA_1$, consisting just of the true
$\Pi_1$ assertions. But recognizing whether a given
$\Pi_1$ assertion is true or not (that is, recognizing it as an axiom of $TA_1$) is exactly as difficult
as recognizing whether a given Diophantine equation has solutions in the integers or not.

This last difficulty is inherent in the problem, since any theory correctly proving whether the polynomials have solutions or not will prove all the instances of $TA_1$. So $TA_1$ a minimal instance of the theory you seek, but it is not clear how useful it is for your purpose, since it is as difficult to recognize the axioms of this theory as it is to solve the problems you intend to solve with it.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, but I am asking not about one theory T but about the whole sequence of theories: ZFC1 consisting of "ZFC+(ZFC is consistent)", ZFC2 is "ZFC1+(ZFC1 is consistent)", etc, and for any ordinal $\alpha$ we get theory $ZFC_\alpha$. If we try to say that union of all this theories is T and apply your argument, that your polynomial $p_T$ will be resolved by next theory in a sequence: "T+(T is consistent)"! So, no particular theory T will help for ALL equations, but for every particular equation we can hope to find a corresponding theory in sequence which will resolve it.

Comment: It is important, that all the axioms are easy to recognize here, and the problem "We cannot tell if a proof is legitimate, because we cannot even recognize the axioms" do not arise with this sequence.

Comment: A uniform description of the tower of theories $T_n$ leads to a description of the union theory $\bigcup_n T_n$, to which the $p_T$ objection still applies. And if you can't describe the tower of theories, then it seems you can't (uniformly) recognize your axioms, and so the other objection applies.

Comment: You don't need to work above ZFC, since as I explained $TA_1$ suffices, and this is provably the minimal theory to do so. This theory is a tower of finitely axiomatizabble theories $T_n$, where one adds the answer for one polynomial in each step. In this way, each $T_n$ is c.e., and we can prove that we can recognize the axioms of each individual $T_n$ separately, and the union settles all Diophantine equations. So this tower satisfies your properties. But we cannot uniformly describe the tower, and similarly for any such tower of theories that succeeds.

Comment: By the way, the specific tower of consistency theories you mention is discussed in this MO question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12865/using-consistency-to-create-new-axioms-in-set-theory

Comment: And thus, if large cardinals are consistent, then there will still remain Diophantine equations not settled by your tower.

Comment: The point being that there are single theories, such as ZFC+Inaccessible which are thought likely to be consistent and that imply the entire tower of consistency statements in the tower you mention. So the $p_T$ for these theories $T$ will be Diophantine equations not settled by your tower.

Comment: The point of this sequence is that 1) all axioms seems to be recognizable but 2) there is no union theory in the sequence, because if T is the one, then "T+(T is consistent)" is not in T. So I hope it can help. But, if the whole tower is included in a single theory ZFC+Inaccessible, so, clearly, nothing interesting can happen here. Thank you.

Comment: Bogdan, the axioms of the tower are not uniformly recognizable, since you need to describe the ordinals $\alpha$ in the twoer in order to describe the $\alpha$-th theory, but the collection of programs that compute well-ordered relations on $\omega$ is not computable. That is, eventually it becomes too difficult to recognize whether a statement appears in your tower, since it becomes too difficult even to recognize the ordinal itself, and your tower can proceed only so long as the ordinal itself is describable in ZFC, since otherwise you cannot formulate the $Con(T_\lambda)$ statement.

Comment: Now I do not understand "recognizable" here. Yes, in Theory "all true statements are axioms" it is hard to say if "twin prime conjecture" is axiom or not. But suppose a theory has reflexivity axiom in the form "x-x=0". Now what about statement S: "x-x = (0 if twin prime conjecture holds, 1 otherwise)". Do we have the same problem "this is axiom if and only if twin prime conjecture holds"? I would say no. I would say that this is not an axiom in any case. This is not my problem to recognize if some complicated description is 0 or not. 


Comment: Similarly, if we denote axioms in tower $T_\alpha$, $\alpha$ ordinal, then statement "$T_{\omega 2 + 1}$, where $\omega$ is the least infinite ordinal" is axiom. In contrast, statement "$T_\alpha$, where $\alpha$ = (some complicated description such that it is not clear if it is ordinal or not)" is not an axiom, similarly to statement S above. So, I agree, that not all axioms in towel can be formulated and "we can proceed only so long as the ordinal itself is describable in ZFC". But, if some statement IS formulated, it should be easy to say if it is axiom or not.  

Comment: In order for $Con(T_\alpha)$ to be expressible in the language, the theory $T_\alpha$ must be describable, and for this, it would seem that $\alpha$ must be describable. My point was first merely that our ability to uniformly describe ordinals this way must eventually give out (this point is mentioned in the answers to the other quesiton). And second, that even if we restrict ourselves to computable ordinals (the sup is known as $\omega_1^{CK}$, after Church and Kleene), then the collecttion of TM programs enumerating well-ordered relations is not a computable set---it is complete $Pi^1_1$.